# How to kill parent process before the completion of the child?

Tags: c, process, fork

I need to parent process **ended earlier** than the child process.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
main()
{
    extern int errno;
    extern char* sys_errlist[];
    pid_t pid;
    int rv;
    switch(pid=fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf(" CHILD: This is child-process!\n");
            printf(" CHILD: My PID -- %d\n", getpid());
            printf(" CHILD: My parent PID -- %d\n", getppid());
            sleep(3);
            printf(" CHILD: My new parent PID -- %d\n", getppid());//I think, that getppid() return 1 
            printf(" CHILD: Exit!\n");
            exit(rv);
        default:
            printf("PARENT: This is parent-process!\n");
            printf("PARENT: My PID -- %d\n", getpid());
            printf("PARENT: My child PID %d\n",pid);
            printf("PARENT: Exit!\n");
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure that it is correct.
The output of this program:

```
PARENT: This is parent-process!
PARENT: My PID -- 943
PARENT: My PID -- 943
PARENT: My child PID -- 944
PARENT: Exit!
CHILD: This is child-process!
CHILD: My PID -- 944
CHILD: My parent PID -- 1
CHILD: My new parent PID -- 1
CHILD: Exit!
```

Thanks!
PS. I'm sorry for my English

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your English was completely understandable. I would write "I need the parent process to end earlier than the child process".

Comment: The follow up question is why you need the parent to end sooner.  If it is just for basic testing purposes you could simply put a sufficiently long `sleep` in the child and exit the parent.  Or do you need a more durable solution for a real problem?  If so, you should explain what that problem is.

Comment: @Duck: there are many reasons for wanting a child process to outlive its parent, not least of which is when the parent starts a background or daemon process.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I was trying to get OP to elaborate on that point.  If his goal was to just see that the child gets inherited by init then his current run already shows that but maybe he has a larger goal in mind in which this was just a verification of step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your parent process exited before the child even started sleeping. This is possible because your parent doesn't do anything that takes a significant amount of time after creating the child. It just prints and exits. So the child saw PPID 1 even before the sleep.

If you add a `sleep(1)` to the end of the parent, there will be a much better chance that the child will print 2 different PPIDs.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to do some actual synchronization to get your processes running the steps in the right order. Sleeps aren't great for that because you can't control how much time the *other* stuff takes (including time that your processes aren't running at all because something else took the CPU).

Answer (score 1):

The output looks fine. The parent process appears to be exiting; the child process is not affected by the parent dying and continues to print its output too.

You can see that the child's parent changed when the parent exited; orphans are inherited by process ID 1, which is simply sitting there waiting for children to die.  PID 1 is classically the `init` process (though on Mac OS X, for example, it is `/sbin/launchd`).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you seem to lack is some form of synchronisation between the two processes that can be acheived for instance via signals, pipes, etc ... you choose

To ensure the order of execution:

- the parent after the `fork()` print its stuff, tell the child to wake
  up and exit immeditly after
- the child wait before it's waked up and then print its own stuff on his turn.

`sleep()` is **not** a synchronization primitive (but can be handy for simple stuff)